# VB.NET ERR: 0x8007000B (Bad Image Format Exception)

Tags: vb.net, image, format, pinvoke

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl  memcopy(void *pDst, const void *pSrc, unsigned int nSize) {             __asm {
                    mov esi, pSrc
                    mov edi, pDst
                    mov ecx, nSize $L1:
                    movq mm7, [esi]
                    add esi, 8
                    movq [edi], mm7
                    add edi, 8
                    dec ecx
                    jne $L1             };  }
```

This is the Code from CopyBlit8x8.dll

I successfully imported this .dll into a C++ Console Application and copied a string 'Hello World' from char * a, to char * b. Then echoed b succesfully showing 'Hello World'.

Then, as this is a generic memory copy routine that accepts two pointers to perform the copy, I did this below;

[image: VB.NET Error In Picture Format]

The picture basically said about the post title ~ Bad Image Format Exception. Err Code: 0x8007000B.

This is a generic error with little information as it applies to  variety of scenarios. But, I can safely assume, its something to do with pointers.

What I want is a fast ASM module to perform generic memory copies,but for vb.NET images.

Any tips, Stack Overflow!

Comment: http://shotting.cc/soapbox/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=10&p=11#p11 This is a link to the authors original post.

Comment: Don't know if it's related to the problem, but the first parameter is the _destination bitmap_ where the data will be put, and the second parameter is the _source bitmap_ from where the data will be copied. And currently you are trying to copy an empty bitmap to a non-empty one.

Comment: Apologies, VVincent, for the mistake in image code. The result is the same for bm2 < bm and bm < bm2. Same errors. Thanks for the heads up all the same.

Comment: See, I find it interesting that I get an 'BAD IMAGE FORMAT', exception, but I get Attempt was made to load a program with incorrect format? Error.

Comment: Well I was being a bit stupid not remebering what the error is actually about :p. Here, _"Image"_ refers to the DLL, not a bitmap image. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

A [**BadImageFormatException**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is thrown when you try to load an assembly or dll that is compiled under a different bitness than the application. For instance if you try to load a 32-bit dll in a 64-bit application (or vice versa).

Make sure that the dll is compiled in the same bitness as the application. If the application is compiled as `AnyCPU` then either force it to be `x86` or `x64`, ***or*** compile two dlls using each bitness, then import each function (but with different names) and call the correct one after checking the [**`Environment.Is64BitProcess` property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess).

This is an example of the `AnyCPU` solution:

```
'32-bit dll
<DllImport("CopyBlit8x8.dll")> _
Public Shared Function memcopy(<insert parameters here>)
End Function

'64-bit dll
<DllImport("CopyBlit8x8_x64.dll")> _
Public Shared Function memcopy64(<insert parameters here>)
End Function

Public Sub DoStuff()
    If Environment.Is64BitProcess = True Then
        memcopy64(...) 'Call 64-bit dll
    Else
        memcopy(...) 'Call 32-bit dll
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT:**

According to Hans Passant, ASM MMX instructions can't be used in x64, so my solution above would not work for you. However I'm leaving it there because it works for DLLs compiled using native C/C++ code.

Comment: This solution cannot work, that assembly code can only ever run in a 32-bit process.  MMX instructions were discontinued in x64.  Only good advice is to eliminate it completely, it is not optimal code at all since it doesn't properly take care of alignment.  And it is hard to use correctly with high odds of memory corruption, the "100" argument in the screenshot is completely arbitrary.  Problems that Marshal.Copy() and the System.Buffer class don't not have.

Comment: @HansPassant : I wasn't aware of that. Thank you!

Comment: @HansPassant : Perhaps you should write an answer about it? I'm not familiar with ASM or its implementation.

Comment: I'm not that fond of *don't do that* answers, SO users hate them.  And I saw "100" reasons not to answer it :)  I'm just trying to help you post a better answer, that's all.  Feel free to ignore the advice.

Comment: @HansPassant : I wasn't hostile against your suggestion, it's just that I don't really know what more to say as I am not familiar with ASM.

Answer (score 0):

Code: Select all

```
__declspec(dllexport) int  __cdecl testApp(long *dst, long *src)
{

   __asm {
         mov eax, src
         mov dst, eax
   };

   return *dst;
}
```

This code above is the working copy operation.

Code: Select all

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text
Imports wow64

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim bm As New Bitmap("1.png")
        Dim bm2 As New Bitmap(640, 400)

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        sb.Append("Helo World.")

        Dim src() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello")
        Dim dst() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("World")

        Dim a As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(10)
        Dim o As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(10)
        Dim i() As Integer = {2, 1}
        Marshal.Copy(i, 0, o, 2)
        a = (wow64.movq.testApp(a, o))
        Button1.Text = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetChars(src)
        TextBox1.Text = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(a, 4).ToString
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(a)
        'Marshal.FreeHGlobal(o)


    End Sub
End Class
Namespace wow64
    Public Class movq

        <DllImport("D:\CopyBlit8x8.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> Public Shared Sub memcopy(ByRef pDsc As StringBuilder, ByRef pSrc As StringBuilder, ByVal nSize As Integer)

        End Sub
        <DllImport("D:\CopyBlit8x8.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> Public Shared Function myPuts(ByRef str As StringBuilder) As Integer

        End Function
        <DllImport("D:\CopyBlit8x8.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> Public Shared Function testApp(ByRef i As Long, ByRef p As Long) As Integer

        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

This code is the copy operation implemented in VB.NET.

Code: Select all

```
TextBox1.Text = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(a, 4).ToString
```

This marshal routine uses 4^increments to read through the array.

Simple, eh?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'm surprised that MMX instructions were discontinued in x64 since the x64 architecture book is where I got the MMX copy operation. That said, I'm implementing this x86 code (32-bit) on x64-bit machines just fine. See, nothing really gets left out the Intel CPU when upgrades happen. This is why on a x64 arch machine its possible to mov al, bl even though we hardly need to do that anymore. Also, MMX instructions are available on x64 machines ~ but as a by-product of 32-bit architecture. For instance, the mm7 register is 64-bits in size, as a rax register is 64-bits.

Comment: @shotting.cc : Did you just answer your own question under a different account? In the answerer's title it says "shotting.cc". FYI if it was you, you are allowed to answer your own question with the same account.

Comment: Hi Vincent, I was at a different computer at a different location without the correct login details so I used my Google Account to post the answer.